# Trying to filter items in a listview, trough another activity, how to update the listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

I have looked trough some samples on google/stack and didnt find any good solution for my problem.

i got, in the activity where the listview is shown, a filter made(winesCopy is a copy of the wines list):

```
public static List<Wine> filterWinesString(List<Wine> wines, Object filterItem)
    {
        for(Wine o : wines)
        {
            if(o.getColor().equals((String)filterItem)||o.getCountry().equals((String)filterItem)||o.getDescription().equals((String)filterItem)||o.getTaste().equals((String)filterItem)||
                    o.getBiologic().equals(filterItem)||o.getSparkling().equals(filterItem)||filterItem.equals(o.getYear()))
            {
                filteredList.add((Wine) o);
            }
        }
        if(!filteredList.equals(null))
        {
            wines= filteredList;
        return wines;
        }
        else{
            return wines;
        }
    }

    public static void clearFilter()
    {
        filteredList.clear();
        wines=winesCopy;
    }
```

and in the activity that i use as the "dialog":

```
Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_btn_add_filter);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  if(!etLand.equals(null))
                  {
                  ListWineView.filterWinesString(ListWineView.winesCopy,etLand.getText().toString());
                  }
                  if(!etTaste.equals(null)){
                      ListWineView.filterWinesString(ListWineView.winesCopy,etTaste.getText().toString());
                  }
                  if(!etYear.equals(null)){
                      ListWineView.filterWinesString(ListWineView.winesCopy,etYear.getText().toString());
                  }
                  if(cbBiologic.isChecked()){
                      ListWineView.filterWinesString(ListWineView.winesCopy, "true");
                  }else{
                      ListWineView.filterWinesString(ListWineView.winesCopy, "false");
                  }
                  if(cbMouserend.isChecked()){
                      ListWineView.filterWinesString(ListWineView.winesCopy, "true");
                  }else{
                      ListWineView.filterWinesString(ListWineView.winesCopy, "false");
                  }
                  if(spinner1.getSelectedItemId()!=0){
                      ListWineView.filterWinesString(ListWineView.winesCopy,spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                  }


                  ListWinesViewFilterActivity.this.finish();
              }
        });

      }
```

i thought i should use the notifyDatasetChange() here:

```
btnFilter.setText("Filter");
    btnFilter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ListWineView.this, ListWinesViewFilterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

but the listview is not refreshing.

**EDIT** i have now changed a bit of the code, and got it working.

solution posted as answer.

Comment: try to write the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); befor startActivity();

Comment: i tried that silvia, but that didnt work either.

Comment: then try to set the adapter to the listview again. like this: listview.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
startActivity(i);
//adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//lv.setAdapter(adapter);
Tried this, or after startactivity, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**activity where the filter method is put**

```
 public static List<Wine> filterByCountry(String country) {
            if (country.equals("")) {
                return wines;
            }
            ArrayList<Wine> winesFil = new ArrayList<Wine>(wines);
            for(Wine wine : winesFil) {
                if (!wine.getCountry().contains(country)) {
                    filteredList.remove(wine);
                }
            }
            return filteredList;
        }
        public static List<Wine> filterByTaste(String taste) {
            if (taste.equals("")) {
                return wines;
            }
            ArrayList<Wine> winesFil = new ArrayList<Wine>(wines);
            for(Wine wine : winesFil) {
                if (!wine.getTaste().contains(taste)) {
                    filteredList.remove(wine);
                }
            }
            return filteredList;
        }
        public static List<Wine> filterByYear(int year ) {
            if (Integer.valueOf(year)==null) {
                return wines;
            }
            ArrayList<Wine> winesFil = new ArrayList<Wine>(wines);
            for(Wine wine : winesFil) {
                if (wine.getYear()!=year) {
                    filteredList.remove(wine);
                }
            }
            return filteredList;
        }

        public static List<Wine> filterByBiologic(boolean biologic) {
            if (!biologic) {
                return wines;
            }
            ArrayList<Wine> winesFil = new ArrayList<Wine>(wines);
            for(Wine wine : winesFil) {
                if (wine.getBiologic()!=biologic) {
                    filteredList.remove(wine);
                }
            }
            return filteredList;
        }

        public static List<Wine> filterBySparkling(boolean sparkling) {
            if (!sparkling) {
                return wines;
            }
            ArrayList<Wine> winesFil = new ArrayList<Wine>(wines);
            for(Wine wine : winesFil) {
                if (wine.getSparkling()!=sparkling) {
                    filteredList.remove(wine);
                }
            }
            return filteredList;
        }

        public static List<Wine> filterByColor(String color) {
            if (color.equals("all")) {
                return wines;
            }
            ArrayList<Wine> winesFil = new ArrayList<Wine>(wines);
            for(Wine wine : winesFil) {
                if (!wine.getCountry().contains(color)) {
                    filteredList.remove(wine);
                }
            }
            return filteredList;
        }

        public static void clearFilter()
        {
            adapter.clear();
            for(Wine wine : winesCopy)
            {
            adapter.add(wine);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            filteredList = new ArrayList<Wine>(wines);
        }

        public static void setFilter()
        {
            adapter.clear();
            for(Wine wine : filteredList)
            {
            adapter.add(wine);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

**activity where the filtering input is given:**

```
 @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                    ListWineView.clearFilter();
                    ListWineView.filterByCountry(etLand.getText().toString());
                    if(!etYear.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    ListWineView.filterByYear(Integer.valueOf(etYear.getText().toString()));
                    }
                    ListWineView.filterByTaste(etTaste.getText().toString());
                    ListWineView.filterByBiologic(cbBiologic.isSelected());
                    ListWineView.filterBySparkling(cbMouserend.isSelected());
                    ListWineView.filterByColor(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    ListWineView.setFilter();
                    ListWinesViewFilterActivity.this.finish();
              }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

try startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() and in onActivityResult() if the control is returned from the dialog activity, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()